# To find the depth of the Graph in Graph Database using Gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

Given a directed graph with V vertices and E edges. How can we obtain the height of the graph using the Gremlin commands?Assume that each edge has a value "knows". 
[The sample graph is given here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOhWf.gif).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Daniel's answer to this other question:

[Print hierarchical vertices in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645066/output-all-ancestors-of-a-given-vertex-of-a-tinkerpop-graph-in-gremlin-console)

i.e. if you want to start at vertex 42, use:

```
g.V(42).emit().repeat(out('knows').dedup()).count()
```

If you wanted to start at a vertex with a given property, e.g. 'name' is 'HEART94', then specify that instead, i.e:

```
g.V().has('name','HEART94').emit().repeat(out('knows').dedup()).count()
```

Hope that helps,
  Graham